# My question on twins and hysterectomies is totally justified

Tags: discussion

That [Does having had twins lead to a hysterectomy later on?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/19623/11231)  is a valid question that has been carefully written. It doesnt need your rules on research because it uses first principles – that of weight downwards leading to muscular strain later in life.

I will not change it. I cannot see anything wrong with asking it.

Answer (score 7):

Suit yourself. The community has established minimum standards for questions. Refusing to meet those standards has a predictable outcome. Your options now are to edit the question to comply and then hoping it gets sufficient votes to be reopened, writing a new question that complies, or simply abandoning the question.